# Как старый проект залить на Git

Tags: git, github

Всем привет. Пишу `git push -u origin master` , мне выдаёт

> ERROR: Repository not found. fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

пишу

```
 git remote add origin git@github.com:phrter-Kushnerevich.git
```

мне выдаёт

> fatal: внешний репозиторий origin уже существует

Как решить проблему? Или как подключиться к моему репу? В гите новый парень, не судите строго

Comment: А Вы на гитхабе создавали такой проект? уже проверил, да там есть такое

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как то имя Вашего репозитория не совсем похоже на реальное. Я бы уточнил.

Самое простое, что Вам можно сделать, это вначале [удалить текущий origin](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-a-remote/)

```
git remote remove origin
```

а потом уже добавить

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:phrter-Kushnerevich.git
```

Но думаю, что этот урл должен выглядеть где то так `git@github.com:phrte/Kushnerevich.git` (там явно должен быть слеш).

Comment: когда пушу, то пишет 
To git@github.com:php-cources/php-oop-file-converter-Kushnerevich.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: не удалось отправить некоторые ссылки в «git@github.com:php-cources/php-oop-file-converter-Kushnerevich.git»
подсказка: Обновления были отклонены, так как внешний репозиторий содержит
подсказка: изменения, которых у вас нет в вашем локальном репозитории.

Comment: подсказка: Обычно, это связанно с тем, что кто-то уже отправил изменения в 
подсказка: то же место. Перед повторной отправкой ваших изменений, вам нужно
подсказка: забрать и слить изменения из внешнего репозитория себе
подсказка: (например, с помощью «git pull …»).
подсказка: Для дополнительной информации смотрите «Note about fast-forwards»
подсказка: в «git push --help».

Comment: Вам рассказывает все, что нужно сделать.